# Is chapter style like this in memoir possible?

Tags: memoir, chapters

I am interested in a chapter style in [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) that resembles this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In anycase, it is easy to obtain with `titlesec`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible. I would start with one of the existing chapter styles and modify that. Have you tried anything? Is there are part that you are specifically having trouble with?  If so, post a minimal compilable document showing what you've got so far and people can help with the specific problems you're having.

Comment: I don't think that is even hard.

Comment: @Bernard, remember `titlesec` is not compatible with `memoir`

Comment: @daleif: I know. I asked just in case the the O.P. were not fixed on memoir.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an adoption of the `demo2` build in memoir chapter style, see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{abir}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\raggedleft \chaptitlefont \MakeTextUppercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \vskip\onelineskip
    \hrule
    \vskip1pt
    \hrule\@height2pt
    \vskip\afterchapskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{3\baselineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \vphantom{\chapnumfont 1}
    \afterchapternum%
    \vskip\topskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{2\onelineskip}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{abir}
\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

test

\chapter*{test star}

test star



\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to create it. I messed up in my code.